# How to open a GMLAS layer in Fiona or GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

I want to open a GMLAS layer.

When I open the file with:

> ogrinfo -ro GMLAS:D:\path\to\file.gml

Output:

> INFO: Open of 'GMLAS:D:\path\to\file.gml'
> using driver 'GMLAS' successful.
>
> ...
>
> 15: roofsurface (Multi Surface)
>
> ...

I tried to open the layer "roofsurface" with Fiona with:

```py
gpd.read_file(r'D:\path\to\file.gml', driver="GMLAS", layer=layer)
```

> Error: DriverError: ... not recognized as a supported file format.

```py
gpd.read_file(r'GMLAS:D:\path\to\file.gml', layer=layer)
```

> Error: unsupported driver: 'GMLAS'

I get the same error in GeoPandas, which internally uses Fiona. Is there another/correct way to open this specific layer in Fiona?

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood Fiona also uses ogr2ogr, you will find GMLAS in the ogr2ogr [driver list](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html). Natively Fiona only supports drivers that are tested to work. You can however make fiona use untested ogr2ogr drivers like this:

```py
import fiona

# print default fiona drivers, that are tested to work
fiona.supported_drivers

# add 'NAS' to supported fiona drivers with read-, append-, write- permisson
fiona.supported_drivers["NAS"] = "raw"
```

Now geopandas will be able to open GMLAS files.

Answer (score 2):

Fiona does not seem to support GMLAS driver. See https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/drvsupport.py

```
# Here is the list of available drivers as (name, modes) tuples. Currently,
# we only expose the defaults (excepting FileGDB). We also don't expose
# the CSV or GeoJSON drivers. Use Python's csv and json modules instead.
# Might still exclude a few more of these after making a pass through the
# entries for each at http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html to screen
# out the multi-layer formats.
```

GMLAS does not appear on the list.